# p:ajax how to get js variable of parent element?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I use some "simple" component like p:commandButton, in its javascript event handler I can refer to "this" variable:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" id="qwer" value="OK" onclick="myJsFunction(this)"/>
```

But, when I deal with p:ajax this trick doesn't work, because p:ajax is not rendered and there's no element to refer to from "this". The question is how to get parent element when calling js handler from p:ajax?

```
<p:commandButton id="qwer" value="OK">
   <p:ajax oncomplete="myJsFunction(this)"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

I know I can just pass the id of parent button and than find it with jquery, but maybe there's some better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oncomplete` doesn't run in the context of the source HTML DOM element. It isn't being relocated to any of its `on*` attributes. It runs in the context of the internal ajax handler. There are three arguments available in this context: `xhr`, `status` and `args` (each with hopefully a self-explaining variable name). In PrimeFaces 5+, the client ID of the source HTML DOM element is available via `xhr.pfSettings.source`.

So, all in all, this should do:

```
<p:ajax oncomplete="myJsFunction(document.getElementById(xhr.pfSettings.source))" />
```

Change if necessary the `myJSFunction` to take `xhr` as argument instead, so that the boilerplate can be reduced in case you intend to reuse it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation!